# Extract Grind-Anchors from Object-Detection API Model

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, coreml, object-detection-api

I'm currently trying to get my SSDLite Network, which I trained with the Tensroflow Object-detection API working, with iOS.

So I'm using the Open Source Code of [SSDMobileNet_CoreML](https://github.com/vonholst/SSDMobileNet_CoreML).

The Graph allready works with some limitations. For running on iOS I had to extract the FeatureExtractor from my Graph and where unable to keep Preprocessor, Posprocessor and MutlipleGrindAnchorBox, same as they did in [SSDMobileNet_CoreML](https://github.com/vonholst/SSDMobileNet_CoreML).

Here you can see the [Anchors](https://github.com/vonholst/SSDMobileNet_CoreML/blob/master/SSDMobileNet/SSDMobileNet/Anchors.swift) they have used.

So cause my Anchors seem to be a little different I tried to undestand how they got this array.

So I found in an GitHub [Issue](https://github.com/tf-coreml/tf-coreml/issues/107#issuecomment-359675509) an explenation, where the User who created the [Anchors](https://github.com/vonholst/SSDMobileNet_CoreML/blob/master/SSDMobileNet/SSDMobileNet/Anchors.swift) explains how he got them.

He says:

> I just exported them out of the Tensorflow Graph from the import/MultipleGridAnchorGenerator/Identity tensor

I allready found the matching tensor in my Graph but I don't know how to export the Graph and retrive the correct Anchor encoding.
Can sombody explain this to me?

Answer (score 1):

I allready figured it out. A little below quote was a link to a [Python Notebook](https://gist.github.com/vincentchu/5f2f669aeb6df9864ec6c43252261269) which explains everything in detail.